# Use condition IF in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app it's *online market*. I can add product to cart.  I am trying change icon  from "add to cart" to "in cart". But it doesn't work correctly. If I add only one product and scroll down, all other products icon also changed. In RecyclerView adapter OnBindViewHolder I use condition ***if***.

```
if (getTableBasket().contains(p.getId()))
    prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
else
    prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);

....

ArrayList<Integer> getTableBasket(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("basket", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In basket 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }
```

**EDIT**
Ok, I am get data from server in JSON format. And display it in recyclerview. I can add prudact to cart, for this I create table "Busket". When user add product to cart, prudact data added to "Busket". And for example user close the app. And again come back to app, he can find that his added product in other icon and didn't added product in another icon.

my db structure

```
db.execSQL("create table basket ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "id_prudact integer,"
                + "name text,"
                + "id_image integer,"
                + "count integer,"
                + "price integer,"
                + "priceOld integer,"
                + "nomer_zakaz text" + ");");

        db.execSQL("create table favorite ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "id_prudact integer,"
                + "name text,"
                + "id_image text,"
                + "count integer,"
                + "price integer,"
                + "priceOld integer" + ");");
```

My Full adapter.

```
public class PrudactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrudactAdapter.PrudactViewHolder> {

    List<PrudactModel> prudactsList;
    public Context mContext;
    public static EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback;
    ArrayList<PrudactBusketModel> busketList = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableBasket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableFavorite = new ArrayList<>();
    String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public PrudactAdapter(List<PrudactModel> persons, Context context){
        this.prudactsList = persons;
        this.mContext = context;


    }

    @Override
    public PrudactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_of_pruduct, parent, false);
        PrudactViewHolder pvh = new PrudactViewHolder(v,mContext);

        return pvh;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);


    }

    @Override
    public void  onBindViewHolder(final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final int i) {

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final PrudactModel p  = prudactsList.get(i);
        prudactViewHolder.catalogName.setText(p.getName());
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setText(Integer.toString(p.getPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setText(Integer.toString(p.getOldPrice())+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.getImgId(),imageLoader);
      //  final MediaPlayer addSound = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.button28);
        //// TODO Cheking PRICE

        if (p.getOldPrice()==0){
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
        }
        else {
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //// TODO Cheking DB

        if (getTableBasket().contains(p.getId()))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);

        if (getTableFavorite().contains(p.getId()))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_d);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  BUY BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

       //// TODO: 02.05.2016  FAVORITE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                }

                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    updateHeartButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.getId());
                    cv.put("name",p.getName());
                    cv.put("id_image",p.getImgId());
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.getPrice());
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.getOldPrice());
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);

                }
                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.getId())});
               }
            }
        });

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  SHARE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.getName()+" за "+p.getPrice()+" тенге. unimax.kz";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });
        prudactViewHolder.btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.getName()+" за "+p.getPrice()+" тенге. unimax.kz";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",p.getImgId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        dbHelper.close();

    }

    private static final AccelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private static final OvershootInterpolator OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator(4);

    private void updateHeartButton(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

                ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
                rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
                rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

                ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
                bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
                bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

                ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
                bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
                bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
                bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        holder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_d);
                    }
                });

                animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
                animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
                animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateHeartButton2(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateBuyButton(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateBuyButton2(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prudactsList.size();
    }

    public void setCallback(EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback2){

        callback = callback2;
    }

    public static class PrudactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cv;
        TextView catalogName,catalogPrice,catalogPriceOld;
        NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        ImageButton btn_favorite,btn_share, btn_buy;
        LinearLayout ll_buy,aksia,ll_share,ll_favorite;

        public PrudactViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            catalogName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_catalog);
            catalogPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_catalog);
            catalogPriceOld = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.old_price_catalog);

            btn_buy = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
            btn_share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
            btn_favorite = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.izbrannyi);

            thumbNail = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_catalog);
            aksia = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aksia);
            ll_buy = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_buy);
            ll_share = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_share);
            ll_favorite = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_favorite);

            catalogPriceOld.setPaintFlags(catalogPriceOld.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        }
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableBasket(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("basket", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In basket 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableFavorite(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("favorite", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");
            do {
                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In favorite 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }
}
```

Sorry it's in Russian
[my app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sco4n.jpg)

Comment: @HirenPatel   it's get id of prudact

Answer (score 2):

public class AdapterTrashIncome extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<ObjectIncome> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterTrashIncome(ArrayList<ObjectIncome> getItems, Context context){
    try {
        mContext = context;
        myItems = getItems;
        }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(FILE_NAME, "51: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvContent;
    public CheckBox cbSelect;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        cbSelect = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ObjectIncome objIncome = myItems.get(position);
    String content = "<b>lalalla</b>";
    holder.tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

    //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
    holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
    holder.cbSelect.setChecked(objIncome.isSelected());

    holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //set your object's last status
                objIncome.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Better you can save product is in cart or not in model class like this:

`Product{
   boolean isInCart;
   .....
}`

and give this type of arraylist in recycler adapter. then just one condition:

```
if (getItem(position).isInCart())
prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
else
prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);
```

otherwise it will do forloop on every item which is bad for UI as well as for memory.

If you still not able to get it look around this link:
http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/08/easy-way-to-highlight-selected-rowitem.html
thing is different but he is changing background you want to change an image just context is different but thing is same.

Comment: But I get data from DB. I am confusing

Comment: Ok so your getting data from db that's all right but create arraylist of product models that way you no longer need to do for loop on every product.
can you paste the db structure then i will give a better insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int PHOTO_ANIMATION_DELAY = 600;
private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();


private final Context context;
private final int cellSize;
private final List<String> photos;
private boolean lockedAnimations = false;
private int lastAnimatedItem = -1;

public Adapter_grid_list_profile(Context context) {
this.context = context;
this.cellSize = com.elite.watchme.commonFunctionalityController.ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth(context) / 3;
this.photos = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user_photos));
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = cellSize;
layoutParams.width = cellSize;
layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
return new PhotoViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
bindPhoto((PhotoViewHolder) holder, position);
}

private void bindPhoto(final PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
Picasso.with(context)
.load(FragmentProfileScreen.imageUrlsHorizontal.get(position))
.resize(cellSize, cellSize)
.centerCrop()
.into(holder.ivPhoto, new Callback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
animatePhoto(holder);
}

@Override
public void onError() {

}
});
if (lastAnimatedItem < position) lastAnimatedItem = position;
}

private void animatePhoto(PhotoViewHolder viewHolder) {
if (!lockedAnimations) {
if (lastAnimatedItem == viewHolder.getPosition()) {
setLockedAnimations(true);
}

long animationDelay = PHOTO_ANIMATION_DELAY + viewHolder.getPosition() * 30;

viewHolder.flRoot.setScaleY(0);
viewHolder.flRoot.setScaleX(0);

viewHolder.flRoot.animate()
.scaleY(1)
.scaleX(1)
.setDuration(200)
.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
.setStartDelay(animationDelay)
```